# How to list people below the average in Excel/OpenOffice?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheeet that shows a list of people and how many appointments have been booked for each of them in the past week.

It looks a bit like this:

[image]

I want to make a list underneath that shows the average number of meetings per week and shows people that are below the average, and how many they have booked.

Is there any way to do that in Excel (or OpenOffice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [advanced data filters](http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Filter:_Applying_Advanced_Filters) functionality.